# Django filter values by two columns

Tags: python, django

My models.py is:

```
class FormObject(models.Model):
    pattern = models.TextField(primary_key=False)  # TODO: JSONField with postgres db
    name = models.TextField(default='Test', primary_key=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, primary_key=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    results = models.TextField(blank=True, primary_key=False)  # TODO: JSONField
    # hash which works like link
    ulink = models.TextField(unique=True, null=False, primary_key=True, default=get_uuid4)
    form_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, primary_key=False, unique=False)
    version = models.IntegerField(default=0, primary_key=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('owner', 'form_id', 'version'), )
```

I'm getting QuerySet using User object `user.formobject_set.all()`
And I want to filter values in following way: version will be max and id will be unique
For example, few objects in set (only id and version will be used to filter them):

```
id=1 version=0
id=2 version=0
id=3 version=0
id=3 version=1
id=3 version=2
```

And result should be

```
id=1 version=0
id=2 version=0
id=3 version=2
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? It's not clear from your expected result how that would work. I think the formatting may be working against you because it looks like you're going to pass all of the first block into `filter` and expect one object back but I'm guessing that's not the case.

Comment: @Tom fixed formatting a bit

Comment: Use annotate to get the max version. `.annotate(Max('version'))` and distinct to get unique ids `.distinct('form_id')`.

Comment: @allcaps looks like smth I need, but distinct is not supported by sqlite which I'm using now

Comment: I get that sqlite is in many projects to prototype quickly, but as soon as you dump into limitations you should start using a proper db. How many records do you have? Normally you want to offload getting the correct records to your db. But if this is a small project you can loop over the items and just get the values you need.

Comment: @desu that's correct - SQLite does not support DISTINCT ON fields.
However, if selecting just values is sufficient, you can use
`FormObject.objects.values('form_id').annotate(version=Max('version'))`
which results in
`[{'version': 0, 'form_id': 1}, {'version': 0, 'form_id': 2}, {'version': 2, 'form_id': 3}]`
and the actual query to the db looks as follows
`SELECT "yourapp_formobject"."form_id", MAX("yourapp_formobject"."version") AS "version" FROM "yourapp_formobject" GROUP BY "yourapp_formobject"."form_id"`

Comment: Looks like I should migrate to postgres, I'll try it now, thanks